# getting gradle error for my project Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zze

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

I am getting the error for my project Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzeonly when i am trying to build my project. Below is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my app id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I am getting this error now after adding multidex in gradle.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zze.class

When I am trying to install the application by setting instant run on I am able to generate apk and successfully installed on device.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: If your project is configured for multidex with minSdkVersion 20 or lower, and you deploy to target devices running Android 4.4 (API level 20) or lower, Android Studio disables Instant Run.**

**So, enable multidex as following:**

```
android {    
defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}  
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**create one class like this**

```
public class Multi_Dex extends Application {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

**now in your manifiest file add this**

```
<application
    android:name=".Multi_Dex"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

to solve this problem s, like described on this link : [developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my app id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner .support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```